# Declarar un mismo servicio en varios bundles

Tags: php, symfony2

Buenos días a todos. Estoy desarrollando una aplicación utilizando exactamente Symfony 2.8 y tengo una duda referente a como poder organizar las declaraciones de mis servicios de normalización de entidades. Lo hago de este modo para poder parsear a JSON de forma cómoda y correcta los objetos que almaceno en mi BD, os pego el código para esclarecer un poco de que va el tema:

```
namespace XXX\XXXBundle\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\SerializerAwareNormalizer;
use ...

class ReservaNormalizer extends SerializerAwareNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface {

   public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array()) {
        return [
            'reserva_id'     =>  $object->getId(),
            'reserva_nombre'  =>  $object->getNombre(),
             ...
        ];
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null) {
        return $data instanceof Reserva;
    }

}
```

Tras esto configuro el archivo services.yml (principal, el de app/config) del siguiente modo:

```
services:
    ...

    # JSON Encoder
    default.encoder.json:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder'

    # Serializer
    symfony.serializer:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer'
        arguments:
            0:
                - '@xxx.normalizer.xxx'
                - '@otro.normalizer.mas'
                - '...otro...'
                - '@serializer.normalizer.object'
            1:
                - '@default.encoder.json'
```

Y en el services.yml de cada bundle:

```
services:
    # XXX Normalizer
    xxx.normalizer.xxx:
        class: 'XXX\XXXBundle\Normalizer\XXXNormalizer'
```

Lo que quiero es NO tener que declarar todas las configuraciones de Normalizer en el arguments 0 del fichero de configuración de servicios principal para, de este modo, tener todo mas ordenado y no toda la lista junta.

Si repito el

```
symfony.serializer:
    class: 'Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer'
```

en cada fichero services.yml de cada bundle me da una excepción *A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1)*. Esto imagino que se debe a que al declarar de nuevo el mismo servicio colisiona.

¿Existe algún modo de hacerlo aplicando buenas prácticas?

Gracias por las respuestas de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si tu `symfony.serializer` necesita todos los Normalizers o solo uno en cada llamada, supongo que solo uno, para ello podrías usar `CompilerPass` que te permite modificar una configuracion inicial de un servicio (o de cualquier cosa cargada en el container) incluso dinamicamente.

Podrías bien, ir definiendo la lista de normalizers que necesitas, si necesits todos, o ir cargando dinamicamente solo el que necesitas, si solo necesitas uno.

Los pasos son:
1) definir una clase que extienda de `CompilerPassInterface`
2) añadir esa clase a la clase de tu Bundle

por ejemplo para definer el compilerPass:

```
class ServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('symfony.serializer')
            ->setArguments([
                new Reference($container->getParameter('normalizer1')),
                new Reference($container->getParameter('normalizer2'))
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

y para incluir en la calse de tu bundle

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->addCompilerPass(new ServiceCompilerPass());
}
```

Puedes encontrar un buen articulo aqui: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/02/22/symfony2-manipulating-service-parameters-and-definitions/

Y de aqui puedes sacar algo mas: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-compiler-pass

Espero ayude...

Comment: Tras probarlo de nuevo no es una opción válida. Si llamamos a $container->getDefinition('symfony.serializer') en diferentes bundles da la famosa excepción de "A circular reference has been detected". Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Bueno para resolver ese problema, podrias hacer dos cosas, utilizar Extension en cada uno de tus bundles y utilizar un alias para renombrar los servicios: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html o igual idear algo para solventar la referencia circular. O incluso tambien podrias controlar que cargas en cada Bundle con Extension::prepend http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html. Sincertamente no lo he mirado a fondo, pero es lo primero que se me ocurre ahora mismo...

Comment: Además ahora que lo miro un poco más, creo que tienes un problema de diseño. Es normal que cante un error de referencia circuclar, porque estas definiendo el mismo servicio con el mismo nombre en diferentes partes de la aplicacion (Bundles), aún renombrandolo o creando un alias, estas duplicando codigo. Si lo que quieres es mantener la independencia y reutilizacion de los Bundles, yo crearia un bundle separado, llamemoslo NormailizerBundle donde incluiria el symfony.serializer y todos los normalizers. Y lo llamas desde otros bundles. Incluso lo podrias reutlizar para futuras aplicaciones

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Respondiendo a tu último comentario, esa era mi pregunta, lo que pretendía era declarar en el services principal (el de app/config) un servicio con unos argumentos para luego extenderlo en cada Bundle. La última solución que has dado es mas o menos lo que ahora hago, en vez de crear un Bundle a parte sólo para los normalizers, los escribo todos en el services principal y ya no tengo el error de ref circular. En sí no es un problema pues tengo esta alternativa para solucionarlo, mas bien era por saber si podía "separarlos" para no tenerlos todos juntos. Saludos!